# windows xp tablet pc sdk on mono

Tags: .net, mono, tablet-pc

I've been in development of an app that utilizes the windows tablet pc sdk. The only thing I really use from it is the InkPicture control.

I'm wondering, the InkPicture control obviously isn't built into .NET, but it is a managed object, so would it work under mono?

I'm downloading MOMA now, but I was just wondering if anyone knew already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the API are used within the InkPicture Control. There is no definitive guide, the only best chance is to run it with the MOMA to find out. The other way is to copy the InkPicture dll or library across to mono, and run your compiled application (Make a simple winform application referencing the control and wire up the InkPicture's event handlers) under Mono and fingers crossed. It may work, it may not. You need to keep a close eye on the Mono project page itself to see what's changed or fixed in the buglist.

Generally as a rule, avoid any p/invokes, or specific Win32API calls, if there are p/invokes used, no guarantee it will work but you can get around that by creating a dummy function or a wrapper to the underlying Mono's routines to achieve exactly that.

Other than that, Good luck with the InkPicture control and hope it works out for you :)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I did run MoMA and it didn't find any problems, but I'm going to give it a go on a different machine with Mono installed to be sure.